# How to create a radio button and see if it's checked?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to create a radio button and see if it's checked?

- Windows Vista
- Dev-C++
- Win32 API
- WM styles

Comment: What platform? Windows? Mac OS X? Linux? What toolkit? Qt? Motif?

Comment: There is no standard C++ GUI library, so no.

Comment: Do you seek for a cli answer using plain C++?

Comment: Ridiculous comments, as the question poster said... "its in the tags". C++ and Win32 (We have the language, the platform and the target library).

Answer (score 4):

To find out whether a radio button (or check box) is checked, send the [`BM_GETCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775986(VS.85).aspx) message to the control and check the return value. You will need the `HWND` of your control; to get that from the control ID, call [`GetDlgItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: That sounds painful :( `textBox.Checked` is where it's at.

Comment: @Mark: The Win32 API is pretty low level as far as GUI frameworks go.

Comment: Oh I know. That's *why* it's painful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CreateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28VS.85%29.aspx) or `CreateWindowEx()` with the [button style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951%28VS.85%29.aspx) `BS_RADIOBUTTON` or `BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON` to create one. E.g.:

```
HWND radioButtonHandle = CreateWindow(
    TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("my radio button"), 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_RADIOBUTTON,
    /* ... */);
```